# Trouble Using Feature Columns in TensorFlow

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am using the HR Analytics: Employee Promotion Dataset from the following link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/hr-ana
My goal is to train a tensor flow neural network using this dataset in order to classify whether an employee will be promoted or not. Many of the columns in the dataset are...
numerical values: ['no_of_trainings', 'age', 'previous_year_rating', 'length_of_service', 'awards_won?', 'avg_training_score']
while the rest are...
categorical values: ['department', 'region', 'education', 'gender', 'recruitment_channel'].
I am looking for a good way to transform a dataframe that has categorical and numerical columns into a dataset that can effectively train a neural network. I stumbled upon this documentation for feature columns and it seems like it should give me what I want https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns, but I am getting an error message and am not sure why. Below is the code I have tried so far with the error message.

The directory "data" stores two csv files (train and test) for the training and testing data pre-made from the kaggle link.

```
# Import training data from kaggle download "data"
df = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

# Removing NaN from dataset
df['previous_year_rating'] = df['previous_year_rating'].fillna(0)
df['education'] = df['education'].fillna('None')

#Define variable names for numerical and categorical data
categorical_vars = ['department', 'region', 'education', 'gender', 'recruitment_channel']
numeric_vars = ['no_of_trainings', 'age', 'previous_year_rating', 'length_of_service', 'awards_won?', 'avg_training_score']

# Create Feature Columns
feature_columns = []

# Categorical variables
for var in categorical_vars:
  categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      var, df[var].unique())
  indicator_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column)
  feature_columns.append(indicator_column)

# Numeric variables
for var in numeric_vars:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(var))


# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(df):
    y = df.pop('is_promoted')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df), y))
    return ds

# Create dataset from dataframe using df_to_datas
ds = df_to_dataset(df)

# Set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Create Model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train 
model.fit(ds, epochs=10)
```

Entire Error Message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [150], line 16
     11 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
     12               loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
     13               metrics=['accuracy'])
     15 # Train 
---> 16 model.fit(train_ds, 
     17           epochs=10)

File ~\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file3hf_ppno.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\mjadw\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\mjadw\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\mjadw\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\mjadw\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\mjadw\miniconda3\envs\py310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'dense_features_2' (type DenseFeatures).
    
    Feature (key: age) cannot have rank 0. Given: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'dense_features_2' (type DenseFeatures):
      • features={'employee_id': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)', 'department': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=string)', 'region': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=string)', 'education': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=string)', 'gender': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=string)', 'recruitment_channel': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=string)', 'no_of_trainings': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)', 'age': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)', 'previous_year_rating': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'length_of_service': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)', 'awards_won?': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)', 'avg_training_score': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int64)'}
      • cols_to_output_tensors=None
      • training=True
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? Or any suggestions for a better way to do this? Essentially I am trying to combine numerical and categorical columns into a single dataset. I do not want to just transform categorical columns into integers with LabelEncoder() for example.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the first dimension of each tensorflow dataset element is supposed to be the batch_size. To do this all you have to do is slightly modify the df_to_dataset method:

```
# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(df, batch_size=32):
    y = df.pop('is_promoted')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df), y))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds
```

Also a '?' cannot be in the name of any of your columns since this is incompatible with tf datasets. You can change the name of this column with the pd.rename() method.